# pandas series get specified month data for example: January February March?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
data = [{"content": "11", "title": "刘德华", "info": "2020-01-13", "time": 1578877014},
                  {"content": "22", "title": "刘德", "info": "2020-01-24", "time": 1579877014},
                  {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "2020-02-28", "time": 1582877014},
                  {"content": "55", "title": "app", "info": "2020-02-17", "time": 1581877014},
                  {"content": "22", "title": "appstore", "info": "2019-06-30", "time": 1561877014},
                  {"content": "44", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-02-28", "time": 1582876014},
                  {"content": "33", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-12", "time": 1584000882},
                  {"content": "44", "title": "banana", "info": "2018-03-12", "time": 1520842482},
                  {"content": "55", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-14", "time": 1584154305},
                  {"content": "66", "title": "banana", "info": "2019-03-14", "time": 1552531905},
                  {"content": "77", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-19", "time": 1584586305},
                  {"content": "88", "title": "banana", "info": "2019-11-07", "time": 1573095105},
                  {"content": "77", "title": "banana", "info": "2012-03-05", "time": 1330934123},
                  ]
```

I want to get all the data for March
my code

```
s = pd.Series(data)
s.index =pd.to_datetime([i['time'] for i in self.dt], utc=True, unit='s').tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai')
```

i hope final data all data for March

```
[
{"content": "33", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-12", "time": 1584000882},
{"content": "44", "title": "banana", "info": "2018-03-12", "time": 1520842482},
{"content": "55", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-14", "time": 1584154305},
{"content": "66", "title": "banana", "info": "2019-03-14", "time": 1552531905},
{"content": "77", "title": "banana", "info": "2020-03-19", "time": 1584586305},
{"content": "77", "title": "banana", "info": "2012-03-05", "time": 1330934123},
]
```

I don't know how to write this code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter by months by [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html):

```
s[s.index.month == 3]
```

Or by [`DatetimeIndex.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month_name.html):

```
s[s.index.month_name == 'March']
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do as follows.

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(data)
df[df['title']=='banana']
```

Results:

```
    content info    time    title
5   44  2020-02-28  1582876014  banana
6   33  2020-03-12  1584000882  banana
7   44  2018-03-12  1520842482  banana
8   55  2020-03-14  1584154305  banana
9   66  2019-03-14  1552531905  banana
10  77  2020-03-19  1584586305  banana
11  88  2019-11-07  1573095105  banana
12  77  2012-03-05  1330934123  banana
```

For filtering by month, if it's just one time and you don't need to parse date string, you can just utilize date string format to save effort:

```
df[df['info'].str.contains('-03-')]
```

Results:

```
   content  info    time    title
6   33  2020-03-12  1584000882  banana
7   44  2018-03-12  1520842482  banana
8   55  2020-03-14  1584154305  banana
9   66  2019-03-14  1552531905  banana
10  77  2020-03-19  1584586305  banana
12  77  2012-03-05  1330934123  banana
```

Answer (score 0):

convert into dataframe and perform

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df['info'] = pd.to_datetime(df['info']) 
#enter specific to_datetime parameters if needed

#filter on month = 3
updated_df =  df[df['info'].apply(lambda x:x.month==3)]
print(updated_df.to_dict('records'))

output
[
  {'content': '33', 'info': Timestamp('2020-03-12 00:00:00'), 'time': 1584000882, 'title': 'banana'},
  {'content': '44', 'info': Timestamp('2018-03-12 00:00:00'), 'time': 1520842482, 'title': 'banana'}, 
  {'content': '55', 'info': Timestamp('2020-03-14 00:00:00'), 'time': 1584154305, 'title': 'banana'}, 
  {'content': '66', 'info': Timestamp('2019-03-14 00:00:00'), 'time': 1552531905, 'title': 'banana'}, 
  {'content': '77', 'info': Timestamp('2020-03-19 00:00:00'), 'time': 1584586305, 'title': 'banana'},  
  {'content': '77', 'info': Timestamp('2012-03-05 00:00:00'), 'time': 1330934123, 'title': 'banana'}
]
```